# Interrupting a runnable in executor threadpool

Tags: java, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

Suppose I started 10 threads using executor framework in java. I want to stop/interrupt a callables based on certain conditions later on. What is the best way to do that. I understand future.cancel(true), does not solve the issue.

Comment: You need to call it with `mayInterruptIfRunning == true` and periodically check `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` within your Runnable (and exit if true).

Comment: "a" callable (meaning a certain one) or "all" of them? this is a crucial distinction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [**article.**](https://dzone.com/articles/interrupting-executor-tasks)

*Calling shutdownNow() or cancel() doesn’t stop the ongoing runnable. What these methods do is simply call .interrupt() on the respective thread(s). The problem is, your runnable doesn’t handle InterruptedException (and it can’t). It’s a pretty common problem described in multiple books and articles, but still it’s a bit counterintuitive.*

*In order to do that, you need to do quite a few things.*

- *Extend Runnable*
- *Make the “cancellable” resources (e.g. the input
  stream) an instance field, which provide a cancel method to your
  extended runnable, where you get the “cancellable” resource and
  cancel it (e.g. call inputStream.close())*
- *Implement a custom
  ThreadFactory that in turn creates custom Thread instances that
  override the interrupt() method and invoke the cancel() method on
  your extended Runnable*
- *Instantiate the executor with the custom
  thread factory (static factory methods take it as an argument)*
- *Handle
  abrupt closing/stopping/disconnecting of your blocking resources, in the run()method*

Comment: "generally, the blocking happens outside of your code" - all blocking operations I can think of have a version with a timeout parameter...